# python Read N integers until first character

Tags: python

Using python 3.6, I have alpha numeric strings in below format. Now I need to read from the first occurrence of integer until next char found.

```
asjkf1234alksfl293487293084
9832alkdjsf03940930i2304093
9lads92387498327409
```

Expected result should be:

```
1234
9832
9
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this or should we loop through the string to extract integers?

Comment: Try regex's  library in python , import re.

Comment: As mentioned, check [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `re.search('\d+')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try python's re module .  sorry the code is written in python2.7

```
from re import findall

listOfStrings=['asjkf1234alksfl293487293084','9832alkdjsf03940930i2304093','9lads92387498327409']

for v in listOfStrings:
    res=findall(r'\d+',v)
    print res[0]
```

Comment: need handle the exception if no '\d+' is find.

Comment: expected result is just the first match. `re.search` is better suited for this situation.

Comment: That's right. I don't know how to use re.search . :-D I only knew re.findall  . I will go study re.search . Thanks :-)

Comment: I tried using `search` as per the documentation but received the output <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='9'>. In which `9` is the answer. Any reference how to improvise the query?

Comment: maybe try this? search(r'\d+',v).group()

Comment: what you are getting as output is the match object. To get the match value from the match object you can do: `match.group()`. So your code should be:

`match = re.search(r'\d+', 'string_to_search')
 if match:
    print(match.group())

Comment: from re import search

listOfStrings=['asjkf1234alksfl293487293084','9832alkdjsf03940930i2304093','9lads92387498327409']

for v in listOfStrings:
    res=search(r'\d+',v).group()
    print res

Comment: @healthyPAPAYA `res=search(r'\d+',v).group() ` will throw an exception when there is no match. Before using `group()` make sure you have a match.